# What is the best method for saving shopping cart orders to a database? Saving the items as an array in one row or in multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql

Just looking for advice here. I have a shopping cart website. I will post my php that receives the items and prints them out. However, I am looking to store these orders in my database. Should I... Can I... save multiple items under one row, in one cell like this?

```
{"114":{"id":"114","name":"Raskals Lemon","quantity":1,"price":15,"weight":1,"shopid":"1","shopname":"MMD","type":"Sativa","size":"---","strain":"Sativa","thc":"---","subtype":"Flower"},"117":{"id":"117","name":"Nectarine","quantity":1,"price":15,"weight":1,"shopid":"1","shopname":"MMD","type":"Sativa","size":"---","strain":"Sativa","thc":"---","subtype":"Flower "}}
```

Or would it be better to save all the items and there details as multiple rows and use something like a 'order number' to tie the rows together in future  queries?

Here is the basic php, if it pertains at all to the question.

```
$order = '';

  for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {

    $item_name = 'item_name_'.$i;
    $item_quantity =  'item_quantity_'.$i;
    $item_price = 'item_price_'.$i;
    $item_weight = 'item_weight_'.$i;
    $item_id = 'item_id_'.$i;
    $item_shop = 'item_shopid_'.$i;
    $item_type = 'item_type_'.$i;  
    $item_shopname = 'item_shopname_'.$i;  
    $item_size = 'item_size_'.$i;  
    $item_strain = 'item_strain_'.$i; 
    $item_subtype = 'item_subtype_'.$i; 






$order .= <<<EOT



    <li>

        <h2 style="font-size:14px;">$content[$item_name]</h2>
        <p style="text-indent:5px;padding-top:5px;"><strong>Quantity:</strong> $content[$item_quantity]</p> 
        <p style="text-indent:5px;"><strong>Grams:</strong> $content[$item_weight]</p>
        <p style="text-indent:5px;"><strong>Catagory:</strong> $content[$item_type]</p> 
        <p style="text-indent:5px;"><strong>Sub Catagory:</strong> $content[$item_subtype]</p>      
        <p style="text-indent:5px;"><strong>Size:</strong> $content[$item_size]</p>     
        <p style="text-indent:5px;"><strong>Strain:</strong> $content[$item_strain]</p>




            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>$currency$content[$item_price].00</strong></p>
            <span class="ui-li-count">$i</span>

    </li>








EOT;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't store orders in the database until they get placed. I would store them in the session.

Comment: Something like the latter. FWIW, I would store incomplete orders in the database

Comment: yea after there placed. i want to store them

Comment: but thanks, ill go with the order numbers thing for now unless someone has more details.

Comment: also my wording may have been confusing. its a delivery website. so after the order has been placed i need to have an active order and after its completed it would be updated as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two tables here (third one is what you already have, I assume):

[image: tables structure]

- `order` table is a place where you store every orders. One order = one record in that table. You can have some order-related details here, like delivery address, delivery method etc.
- `order_item` table is a place where you store each ordered item. This has relation of *many to one*. Many ordered items in one order. You have item-releated details here like quantity of given product, size and other stuff.

Comment: I understand and thank you for the detail. I was starting to draw the solution in my head and then you give me a picture. While I have your attention though... I would like to expand. So this means I can have a table with everyone's order items? These items have an ID that will match them up with the order. Then future queries would be done with a JOIN I assume. Also, if I am right when I say, "all the order items end up in one big table". How does that work for a large company like postmates? Do they have millions of items in one table? At what point do you need a new table, or do you?

Comment: Yes, you perform a `JOIN` query to retrieve these records with one query. I don't know how big "postmates" are, but if we are talking about milions of items in `order_item` table, it comes to partitioning when you want to scale (or maybe other solutions I'm not aware of), but all in all it's stored in that particular table.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Just wanted to wrap my head around the concept before I start writing it.

Answer (score 0):

from a real world understanding there is a concept of order header and order lines. So you can design your underlying tables in two different tables with different granularity. For e.g.
Order header table - should contain only the parent information like order number, customer number, order date etc.

Order Line Item table - should contain all the child items, for each order number there could be 1 or more rows with information like order number, item number, quantity etc.

Hope you find this useful.Thanks